# Team Foundation Build Activitie "DownloadFiles" is giving error

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am customizing the default build process template in TFS 2010.

i am using "DownloadFiles" build activity and in server path i have given "$/TFS/Libraries/Foo.DLL", when i run the execute definition its throwing error as "Access to the path '\ServerName\SharedFolder\BuildName\TempFolder' is denied.".

But when i give server path as "$/TFS/Libraries" its downloading all the files in Libraries folder into shared TempFolder.

But i need do download only one file. Please help..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Now, `DownloadFiles` does work for a whole folder only:

- `ServerPath="$/proj/path"` - works great, all is downloaded to `LocalPath`.
- `ServerPath="$/proj/path/name.ext"` - borked.

I've de-compiled `DownloadFiles` to see why: First it gets a list of server items, in our case just `$/proj/path/name.ext`. Then, it calculates the local path like this:

`localItemPath = Path.Combine(LocalPath,`[`VersionControlPath.MakeRelative`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.common.versioncontrolpath.makerelative.aspx)`(ServerItem, ServerPath));`

In this line, the activity assumes that `ServerPath` is a path. If it's not, then `MakeRelative` will not recognize it, and the local path will be `LocalPath/$/proj/path/name.ext`, as the OP has observed.

Also, if `ServerPath` is not canonical - for example, `$/proj/path/../path2`, the same will happen. Solution: use [`VersionControlPath.GetFullPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.common.versioncontrolpath.getfullpath.aspx)`(myNonCanonicalPath)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant the user running the build service with write permissions on the shared folder.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668757.aspx

Comment: Team Foundation Build Service is running under "TFSService" user account, and this account has full control on the shared location and added in the "Project Collection Build Service Accounts".. downloading folder is working fine, but downloading single file has problems.

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate Build activities, `DownloadFiles` for a *folder* ServerItem and a `DownloadFile` for a *single file* ServerItem.
I'd expect it should work with `DownloadFile`.

Comment: `DownloadFile` appears to be deprecated: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg265783.aspx#Activity_Download_Files